# Pushed ViewController Displays Unassigned Background Colors

Tags: ios, swift, background, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

In `storyboard`, I have embedded a `navigationcontroller` in a parent `viewcontroller` that hosts a container `viewcontroller`. Within the container `viewcontroller`, I am pushing another `viewcontroller` onto the stack covering the full screen.

On push however, the screen's background color is red when I've set it to transparent. Additionally, a `collectionview`'s background is also black when it should be white, and finally, there is a dragged out delay on the push animation itself.

Any guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be some bug, but uncovered on a post where if you set the background color to an actual color (white in my case) the issue is resolved, which was the case for me.